# List of Symbols and abbreviations with groups

Tags: symbols, texstudio, acronyms, nomenclature

I'm writing my thesis in this template:
https://dzwaneveld.github.io/report/#document-structure

And I'd like to implement a slightly different nomenclature style.
First off, I'd like to have a separate page for Abbreviations and Symbols.
Both the abbreviations and the symbols should be alphabetically ordered with the latter divided into roman and greek letters.

I attach a screenshot of a setting that I like. I'm using TexStudio for the first time so I'm not quite sure how to make this happen. [image: Ideal structure]

Thank you all for the help!!!

Comment: There remains the option of making the list manually/automatically in some other programming language you're more familiar of — besides, include a minimal working example in the code, don't just use the link.

Comment: @user202729 Unfortunately it will be a year long project, so making the list manually won't work.